# How to prove `plus_le_compat_l : forall n m p, n <= m -> p + n <= p + m.`

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

another problem from SFv1 which got me stuck.

The theorem is as follows:

```
Theorem plus_le_compat_l : forall n m p,
  n <= m ->
  p + n <= p + m.
```

I have tried several avenues so far, the one that got me the furthest was to introduce `n` and start induction on it. The base case is rather trivial (`intros m p H. rewrite add_0_r. apply le_plus_l.`).

As for the inductive step, I have tried to `destruct p`, which gives me two subcases. For the first where `p = O`, it's super easy to prove by applying `H`. When `p = S n` I get stuck. Here's the full proof so far:

```
Theorem plus_le_compat_l : forall n m p,
  n <= m ->
  p + n <= p + m.
Proof.
  intros n.
  induction n as [| n' IHn'].
  - intros m p H. rewrite add_0_r. apply le_plus_l.
  - destruct p eqn:E.
    + intros H. simpl. apply H.
    + intros H. simpl. apply n_le_m__Sn_le_Sm.
```

And my current goal:

```
  n' : nat
  IHn' : forall m p : nat, n' <= m -> p + n' <= p + m
  m, p, n : nat
  E : p = S n
  H : S n' <= m
  ============================
  n + S n' <= n + m
```

I tried a trivial manipulation to turn the LHS of the inequality into `n' + S n` which lets me `rewrite` the `S n` as `p`, but that also doesn't take me anywhere.

Any hints here are highly appreciated :-)

Thanks

PS: I have tried to apply a previously proved theorem without success:

```
Theorem add_le_cases : forall n m p q,
  n + m <= p + q -> n <= p \/ m <= q.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case using induction on `p` is the way to go, and both goals should be quite ok to prove – the induction one by a use of `le_n_S`.

Comment: Thanks Meven!!! That really, really helped!! I seem to have difficulty seeing these possibilities :-(

Comment: @FelipeBalbi I'm pretty late, but did you ever figure this one out? I'm stuck with `(p' + S n' <=? p' + m) = true` as my hypothesis while doing the inductive step

Comment: UPDATE: Sorry, I got stuck with pumping lemma, this one I solved.